# Cannot get rid of whitespace before tables

Tags: tables, spacing, positioning, two-column

I cannot get rid of the white space before my tables. Here's how they look like right now:

[image: Tables]

I've tried to use `!htp` and `\vspace`, but they don't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The key would be to add more text to your document. The alternative, I guess, is that you're working with tables for which you can't insert text to fill the gaps, and that you want them at the top of the page, below one another with the whitespace below them... Yes? No? Please clarify...

Comment: Maybe try the `\raggedbottom`  directive  in your preamble.

Comment: I'm looking to achieve the alternative. I can't add text to fill the gaps, as it's being structured with two columns.

Comment: @Bernard, can you specify on what that command does and what to include in the command?

Comment: The default is `\flushbottom` , which means that latex will play with rubber lengths so that all pages end at the same point of the physical page. In some cases, this behaviour can result in huge vertical spacing. `\raggedbottom` only tries to end pages at the same point, but if it's not possible, it will leave some white space at the bottom of the pag, which can be more acceptable (the horizontal equivalent is `\RaggedRight`, as opposed to ‘justified’).

Comment: I think you might want to post your code.

Comment: @Bernard `\raggedright` ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on the following assumptions:

- You're using a `twocolumn` layout;
- The tables are too wide to fit within the `\columnwidth`, so you're using `table*` - this necessarily pushes them to the (top of) the following page (if there is additional content on that page).

Instead of relying on TeX's floating mechanism for placement, set the float manually using [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) and [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption).

`afterpage` helps provide the correct flow of content within the document, delaying code until the current page is flushed. This may not be necessary, depending on the document structure. For example, if there is no content following the two tables (that is, they are the last things set within the document), a simple `\clearpage would also work rather than wrapping the "float" inside an`\afterpage` command.

`caption` provides the means to set a caption of appropriate type even though you may not be inside a float. Since we're going to set the table manually, we're actually doing so inside a `minipage` and using `\captionof{table}` to set a `table`-like `\caption`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage,caption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\afterpage{%
\noindent
\makebox[\columnwidth][l]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering

    \rule{.7\textwidth}{250pt}% A tabular
    \captionof{table}{This is a caption.}

    \bigskip

    \rule{.8\textwidth}{100pt}% A tabular
    \captionof{table}{This is a caption.}
  \end{minipage}
}}%

\lipsum[5-7]

\end{document}
```

There is no need to place the tables in separate floats. Indeed, I've placed them within the same group (a `minipage`) above. Additionally, care has been taken to make sure the two-column-width block doesn't cause an overfull `\hbox` warning by setting it in a `\columnwidth`-size box.

Note that the `\afterpage{...}` code should be placed within the second column text of the page preceding the "float" placement, as each column under `twocolumn` is similar to a page within `onecolumn` mode.